# Contact form 7 error hiding first time submit on the form

Tags: wordpress

Contact form 7 error hiding first time submit on the form
Please check the below attachemtns [enter image d[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBQWV.png)escription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNSgq.png)

I need solution on this
eror code
** e.wpcf7.parent.querySelector('.screen-reader-response [role="status"]').innerText = "",
**

Comment: The problem is that the element in question is not found in the current document. But we can't possibly tell why, based on just those screenshots. Might be a problem with your theme or something.